# Bootstrap Carousel slide issue (Issue with Handlebars perhaps?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, handlebars.js

Hoping someone can shed some light on an issue I'm having with Bootstraps Carousel and Handlebars.

http://padpeep.com/collection/52

I was hoping this would be simple, handlebars loads in data from PHP into a template that forms the slider. The slider and thumbnail renders but I can't get the thumbs to click and change the slider position to that thumb.

This is the bit that doesnt work. See the console output to show it does get foo (the slide ID) but does not action the click.

```
$('.thumbBtn').on("click", function() {
        //var count = slide id
        var foo = $(this).attr("data-count");

        //log 
        console.log("thumbButtonClick" + foo);

        //change carousel slide
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(foo);

    });
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Property '5' of object # is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I forgot to include the jQuery UI library. Add this line after you include jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></scrip
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add the data attributes to the thumbBtn elements?

```
data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"
```

This should be the default way of getting what you need working.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel